# OutOfMemory exception when using Kotlin ::class.java.canonicalName

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting Out Of Memory exception when running this line of code

```
private val TAG = KotlinFilePicker()::class.java.canonicalName
```

and when disabled it's working fine

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 170 byte allocation with 68 free bytes and 68B until OOM" (recursive case)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7581c250 self=0xb4f07800
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:   | sysTid=20584 nice=-11 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fd7ec8
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1394 stm=35 core=1 HZ=100
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:   | stack=0xbe57a000-0xbe57c000 stackSize=8MB
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:46)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.<init>(FragmentHostCallback.java:63)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:871)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:100)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepickersample E/art:     at com.androidbuffer.kotlinfilepicker.KotlinFilePicker.<init>(KotlinFilePicker.kt:19)
01-04 00:14:55.044 20584-20584/com.android
```

can someone point out what's wrong doing this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
private val TAG = KotlinFilePicker::class.java.canonicalName
```

instead?

Since your stacktrace states the following:

```
Failed to allocate a 170 byte allocation with 68 free bytes and 68B until OOM" (recursive case)
```

Which means we have an endless recursion here. Taking a closer look at the code, we see that you create an instance of a class, which tries to create the `TAG` property, which in turn creates another instance of `KotlinFilePicker`... until all memory exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `KotlinFilePicker()` which has it's own TAG which creates a new `KotlinFilePicker()` ect.

To fix it use `KotlinFilePicker::class.java.canonicalName`.